# How to combine multiple SWF (with only 1 frame) files into one SWF?

Tags: batch-processing, adobe-flash, swf

How to combine multiple SWF (with only 1 frame) files into one SWF?

Preferably using a freeware in windows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about the nerdy answer, but [swftools](http://www.swftools.org/) can be an option.

Once you launch a command line interface you should be able to navigate to the swftools folder and run the swfcombine tool passing your main target swf filename followed by the paths to the .swf files you want to combine.

Tool reference is available [here](http://wiki.swftools.org/wiki/Main_Page)

> **swfcombine** - multi-function tool for SWF insertion into wrapper SWFs, SWF concatenation, stacking, and basic parameter manipulation (e.g. size change )

```
Usage: ./swfcombine [-rXYomlcv] [-f] masterfile [-xysf] [(name1|#id1)=]slavefile1 .. [-xysf] [(nameN|#idN)=]slavefileN
OR: ./swfcombine [-rXYomv] --stack[1] [-xysf] [(name1|#id1)=]slavefile1 .. [-xysf] [(nameN|#idN)=]slavefileN
OR: ./swfcombine [-rXYov] --cat [-xysf] [(name1|#id1)=]slavefile1 .. [-xysf] [(nameN|#idN)=]slavefileN
OR: ./swfcombine [-rXYomlcv] --dummy [-xys] [file]
-o , --output <outputfile>      explicitly specify output file. (otherwise, output.swf will be used)

-t , --stack                   place each slave in a seperate frame (no master movie)
-T , --stack1                  place each slave in the first frame (no master movie)
-m , --merge                   Don't store the slaves in Sprites/MovieClips
-a , --cat                     concatenate all slave files (no master movie)
-l , --overlay                 Don't remove any master objects, only overlay new objects
-c , --clip                    Clip the slave objects by the corresponding master objects
-v , --verbose                 Be verbose. Use more than one -v for greater effect 
-F , --flashversion            Set the flash version of the output file.
-d , --dummy                   Don't require slave objects (for changing movie attributes)
-f , --frame                   The following identifier is a frame or framelabel, not an id or objectname
-x , --movex <xpos>            x Adjust position of slave by <xpos> pixels
-y , --movey <ypos>            y Adjust position of slave by <ypos> pixels
-s , --scale <scale>           Adjust size of slave by <scale> percent (e.g. 100% = original size)
-r , --rate <fps>              Set movie framerate to <fps> (frames/sec)
-X , --width <width>           Force movie bbox width to <width> (default: use master width (not with -t))
-Y , --height <height>          Force movie bbox height to <height> (default: use master height (not with -t))
-N , --local-with-networking     Make output file "local-with-networking"
-G , --hardware-gpu            Set the "use hardware gpu" bit in the output file
-B , --accelerated-blit        Set the "use accelerated blit" bit in the output file
-L , --local-with-filesystem     Make output file "local-with-filesystem"
-z , --zlib <zlib>             Enable Flash 6 (MX) Zlib Compression
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry about the late reply. I had tried this before I asked the question, but I did not point it out. The tool only supports up to 150 singles on my Windows 7 X64 in a single run.

Answer (score 0):

[Vectorian Giotto](http://vectorian.com/giotto/) is a freeware SWF editor, the UI looks kinda like the Adobe Flash one so if you have used that one before you can get used to it

Another option is you can convert your swf's to gifs and open them in photoshop, combine the frames and export it to a gif